# Pandas Correlation Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, correlation

Assuming I have a dataframe similar to the below, how would I get the correlation between 2 specific columns and then group by the 'ID' column?  I believe the Pandas 'corr' method finds the correlation between all columns.  If possible I would also like to know how I could find the 'groupby' correlation using the .agg function (i.e. np.correlate).

What I have:

```
ID  Val1    Val2    OtherData   OtherData
A   5       4       x           x
A   4       5       x           x
A   6       6       x           x
B   4       1       x           x
B   8       2       x           x
B   7       9       x           x
C   4       8       x           x
C   5       5       x           x
C   2       1       x           x
```

What I need:

```
ID  Correlation_Val1_Val2
A   0.12
B   0.22
C   0.05
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You pretty much figured out all the pieces, just need to combine them:

```
>>> df.groupby('ID')[['Val1','Val2']].corr()

             Val1      Val2
ID                         
A  Val1  1.000000  0.500000
   Val2  0.500000  1.000000
B  Val1  1.000000  0.385727
   Val2  0.385727  1.000000
```

In your case, printing out a 2x2 for each ID is excessively verbose.  I don't see an option to print a scalar correlation instead of the whole matrix, but you can do something simple like this if you only have two variables:

```
>>> df.groupby('ID')[['Val1','Val2']].corr().iloc[0::2,-1]

ID       
A   Val1    0.500000
B   Val1    0.385727
```

#### For the more general case of 3+ variables

For 3 or more variables, it is not straightforward to create concise output but you could do something like this:

```
groups = list('Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3', 'Val4')
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range( len(groups)-1): 
    df2 = df2.append( df.groupby('ID')[groups].corr().stack()
                        .loc[:,groups[i],groups[i+1]:].reset_index() )

df2.columns = ['ID', 'v1', 'v2', 'corr']
df2.set_index(['ID','v1','v2']).sort_index()
```

Note that if we didn't have the `groupby` element, it would be straightforward to use an upper or lower triangle function from numpy.  But since that element is present, it is not so easy to produce concise output in a more elegant manner as far as I can tell.

Comment: How would I change this to 'rolling_corr()' so that the rolling correlation is calculated every 10 days?

Comment: This is a great answer. The fact that to something this simple involves having to mess around with `.iloc`s is one of the things which really frustrates me about pandas; if I want to set up a large processing pipeline for scientific data, I end up feeling like everything's held together with toothpaste.

Answer (score 14):

One more simple solution:

```
df.groupby('ID')[['Val1','Val2']].corr().unstack().iloc[:,1]
```

Answer (score 6):

In the above answer; since ix has been depreciated use iloc instead with some minor other changes:

```
df.groupby('ID')[['Val1','Val2']].corr().iloc[0::2][['Val2']] # to get pandas DataFrame
```

or

```
df.groupby('ID')[['Val1','Val2']].corr().iloc[0::2]['Val2'] # to get pandas Series
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining other's answers to something that does not rely on implicit indices.

Getting correlation by group is relatively simple:

```py
corr_df = op_data\
    .groupby('ID')[['Val1', 'Val2']]\
    .corr().unstack()[[('Val1', 'Val2')]]\
    .reset_index()
```

```
  ID      Val1
          Val2
0  A  0.500000
1  B  0.385727
2  C  0.714575
```

Now, to get the desired flat column structure we can use some [tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64982555/3494126)

```py
corr_df.columns = corr_df.columns.map(lambda x: '_'.join(a for a in x if len(a)>0))
```

```
  ID  Val1_Val2
0  A   0.500000
1  B   0.385727
2  C   0.714575
```

---

p.s. to parse OPs data:

```py
for rep in range(10):
    data_str = data_str.replace('  ', ' ')
op_data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data_str), sep=' ', engine='python')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also need to keep the structure of your dataframe here's what I came up with:

Assuming you start with this dataframe:

[image]

```
corr_df = x.groupby('ID')[['Val1','Val2']].corr().unstack()
corr_df.columns = ['Correlation_Val1_Val1', 'Correlation_Val1_Val2', 'Correlation_Val2_Val1', 'Correlation_Val2_Val2']
corr_df = corr_df.reset_index().drop(columns=['Correlation_Val1_Val1', 'Correlation_Val2_Val2', 'Correlation_Val2_Val1']) 'v2v1cor', 'v2v2cor'])
```

which results in:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly this also works, with elegant output

```
    df.groupby('ID')['Val1'].corr(df['Val2'])
```